# Editing innerText of <a>link</a> disables clicking of link

Tags: javascript

My function replaces the letter 'o' with a flower after 9 seconds of inactivity.

When I utilize this on a link, such as `<a href="google.com">Click on me</a>` the link cannot be clicked.

This only occurs in Safari. I'm using version version 11.1.2. It works in Chrome and Firefox.

What is Safari doing differently that creates this issue?

I figured out that the w `window.onmousedown` event listener was the culprit. It was messing with the ability to click a link in Safari.

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.flowerText');
var functionIsRunning = false;


function elementSelector(x, y) {
  var strNewNew = elements[x].innerText;
  var oneMoreFlower

  function changeToFlowers() {
    if (functionIsRunning) {
      return;

    }
    oneMoreFlower = strNewNew.replace(/o/, "✿");
    elements[x].innerText = oneMoreFlower;
    strNewNew = oneMoreFlower;
    return strNewNew;
  }

  var newVariable = (strNewNew.match(/o/g) || []).length; //logs 3


  function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) { // min and max included 
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < newVariable; i++) {
    var int = randomIntFromInterval(0, 1500);

    setTimeout(changeToFlowers, int)
  }

}
var numOfElements = document.querySelectorAll('.flowerText').length;

function changeToOs() {
  if (!functionIsRunning) {
    functionIsRunning = true;
    elements.forEach(function(company) {
      var textContentVar = company.innerText;
      company.innerText = textContentVar.replace(/✿/g, "o");
      return;
    });
    functionIsRunning = false;
  }
}

function idleLogout() {
  var t;
  window.onload = resetTimer;
  window.onmousemove = resetTimer;
  window.onmousedown = resetTimer; // catches touchscreen presses as well      
  window.ontouchstart = resetTimer; // catches touchscreen swipes as well 
  window.onclick = resetTimer; // catches touchpad clicks as well
  window.onkeypress = resetTimer;
  window.addEventListener('scroll', resetTimer, true); // improved; see comments
  function yourFunction() {
    console.log("inactive");
    for (var i = 0; i < numOfElements; i++) {
      elementSelector([i]);
    }
    changeToOs();

  }

  function resetTimer() {
    console.log("timer has been reset");
    clearTimeout(t);
    t = setTimeout(yourFunction, 9000); // time is in milliseconds
    changeToOs();
  }
}
idleLogout();
console.log(functionIsRunning)
```

```html
<a href="google.com" class="flowerText">GooGLE 1</a><br>
<a href="google.com" class="flowerText">GoOGLE 2</a><br>
<a href="google.com" class="flowerText">GOoGLE 3</a><br>
<a href="google.com" class="flowerText">GOOGLE 4</a><br>
<a href="google.com" class="flowerText">GooGLE 5</a>
```

Comment: Your question title says you are changing the `.innerHTML` of a link, but your code shows you using `.innerText`. I would suggest you try `.textContent` instead.

Comment: The problem persists with .textContent. Link to pen: https://codepen.io/dillonjacobson100/pen/JjGLVyQ. The link even registers the click by turning red. Seems odd to me that it would the linking functionality doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: I noticed that you answered the question yourself in an edit. Please consider writing an answer instead of editing your own post